# Flutter Bloc Cubit update Map in State

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, bloc, cubit

I have a `Map<int,int>` inside my `State` which I want to update at some point. Currently I am updating the map like this:

```
final updatedMap = Map<int, int>.from(state.skipViewsWithSkipValues);
updatedMap[state.currentViewIndex] = _viewsIfMnp.length;

emit(
  state.copyWith(
    skipViewsWithSkipValues: updatedMap,
  ),
);
```

And this works, but seems quite dirty. What is the "clean" way to update a `map` inside a `state` of a `cubit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO this is the right way to do it, if you're discussing the code readability, you may utilize `Map.of` instead of `Map.from`, which uses the same key and value types, so no need to pass the generic types. You may also use the cascade operator mixed with the subscript access, like so:

```dart
emit(
  state.copyWith(
    skipViewsWithSkipValues: Map.of(state.skipViewsWithSkipValues)
        ..[state.currentViewIndex] = _viewsIfMnp.length,
  ),
);
```

Comment: ok got it, that makes sense. Thanks you :)